# How to narrow down the Template Literal Type when used twice

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to narrow down the Template Literal in the following case.

```
type Table = 'Name' | 'Age'
type Separated<S extends string> = `${S}${"" | `, ${S}`}`;
type Expression<T extends string> = `${T}: ${Uncapitalize<T>}`;
type UpdateExpression<T extends string> = `SET ${Separated<Expression<T>>}` 


let expression: UpdateExpression<Table> = 'SET Age: age, Name: name'; // - This should be possible

let expression: UpdateExpression<Table> = 'SET Age: age, Name: age'; // - This should not be possible
```

When I enter `Age:` . The instellisense should suggest the value of  `UnCapitalize<Age>` which results in `age`. It should not compile if any other values are entered.

Is it possible to do in typescript. ?

The solution should satisfy arbitrary number of `Table` unions.

Comment: What's `Table` and what's `Age: <R>` ? There's potentially some gaps in your example

Comment: @mbdavis Updated my Question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `Expression<T>` does not *distribute* `` `${T}: ${Uncapitalize<T>}` `` across unions in `T`; ideally you want `Expression<"a" | "b">` to be equivalent to `Expression<"a"> | Expression<"b">`.  Luckily, you can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to get this behavior:

```
type Expression<T extends string> =
    T extends any ? `${T}: ${Uncapitalize<T>}` : never;
```

By wrapping the original expression in `T extends any ? ... : never`, we've told the compiler to break any unions in `T` into individual members, evaluate the type for each member, and then unite it back into a single union.

---

With that change, `UpdateExpression<Table>` becomes:

```
type UET = UpdateExpression<Table>;
/* type UET = 
     "SET Name: name" | "SET Age: age" | "SET Name: name, Name: name" | 
     "SET Name: name, Age: age" | "SET Age: age, Name: name" | 
    "SET Age: age, Age: age" */
```

which only has valid pairs, as desired. (I'm not considering out-of-scope issues like repeated fields and support for only up to two fields.)

And so this does what you want:

```
let expression: UpdateExpression<Table> = 'SET Age: age, Name: name'; // okay
let expression2: UpdateExpression<Table> = 'SET Age: age, Name: age'; // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDbQLxQOQDk4FsIZQA+mAggOYEBQokUAyhGHAE5zAQAmAPPVBAA8OAO04BnKGOAsAlsPIA+KOgAGAEgDe9AL6aARHuJQVAGiiadK7SoDcNcNACiAsCwhixMgPbDuMfkIQohJSsvJKqFRQ0bABIuJQcMIgUAD8xpow2gBc5hoAqsIAxnBgMsBwSDIAXhB+CtZQucIQAG4QLHa00PlgnOwQzq7unj5+cUEJoXKKysb0jv4WTKwDPENuHt6+MAoNKlT2dPmLc739HBsj236IKAp2APQAVFDdUCf+6FExUHoL-hw+GaeAghhI-1OFAguTglHBfwBUCBMKgwlBZhRIPwCJ+MUhgNB2IgZmhsPhRgJUDJiUomKJaNBuN+VJpcJJ1Mo5LBUGej0OKGAAWGWx8uXOAyuop2dwgEUwSLZdORDPR+AwNigj0eUC8AGs4CAqILhZtRsIAEzivqSlxmm7wZByuYYRVc2kcrEejVanUdFheFgAQiAA)

Comment: The solution does not work if I add another string to Table like 'Order'. Playground link. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDbQLxQOQDk4FsIZQA+mAggOYHGYDyATgCYR0YBQokUAogB5h0QAzoICWAewB2AHhhQIPYBAkNBUQcDoiJ5AHxR0s+YuWq4EkFAD8UAAYASAN4wAvgC4ojgKoSAxnDAiwHBIIgBeEDI6zjZQ7hIQAG7MANzs4NAAyhBgcHRwigxSGXIKSipqGlq6+raOGc6OAESN1DYANB4O9TbRqRzQnmAM+RC8-EKikjIlxuXqmtp66DYZXLJ12bkjhWMCwuLSMDpRMaw+kuol4-uS7oPDirsTBzKIKEuYq7IUEO5wlB0cPg4ngIB16Ew6O4xIxmBhkkA

Comment: As I said, that's out of scope.  Your original code had this problem (`Separated<S extends string>` only accepts up to two values and you put one comma in it) but the question does not mention "number of things in the union" as an issue.  EDIT: oh I see you just edited your question, but that's not really not a single question anymore.  I would suggest you put the "handle arbitrary union lengths" as a separate post.  I am happy to look at it if I get time, but it's difficult to deal with scope creep.